# How can I force spark/hadoop to ignore the .gz extension on a file and read it as uncompressed plain text?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, gzip

I have code along the lines of:

```
val lines: RDD[String] = sparkSession.sparkContext.textFile("s3://mybucket/file.gz")
```

The URL ends in `.gz` but this is a result of legacy code. The file is plain text with no compression involved. However spark insists on reading it as a GZIP file which obviously fails. How can I make it ignore the extension and simply read the file as text?

Based on [this article](https://medium.com/@samuelboyd/spark-reading-gzipped-files-from-s3-without-the-gz-extension-58cc78e6a09d) I've tried setting configuration in various places that doesn't include the GZIP codec, e.g.:

```
sparkContext.getConf.set("spark.hadoop.io.compression.codecs", classOf[DefaultCodec].getCanonicalName)
```

This doesn't seem to have any effect.

Since the files are on S3, I can't simply rename them without copying the entire file.

Comment: Related: There is an [issue on the Spark tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-29280) about adding a way to explicitly specify a compression codec (or no codec) when reading files, so Spark doesn't infer it from the file extension.

Answer (score 5):

First solution: **Shading GzipCodec**

The idea is to **shadow/shade** the `GzipCodec` as defined in the package `org.apache.hadoop.io.compress` by including in your own sources this java [file](https://apache.googlesource.com/hadoop-common/+/HADOOP-6685/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/io/compress/GzipCodec.java) and replacing this line:

```java
public String getDefaultExtension() {
  return ".gz";
}
```

with:

```java
public String getDefaultExtension() {
  return ".whatever";
}
```

When building your project, this will have for effect to use your definition of `GzipCodec` instead of the one provided by the dependencies (this is the shadowing of GzipCodec).

This way, when parsing your file, `textFile()` will be forced to apply the default codec as the one for gzip doesn't fit the naming of your file anymore.

The inconvenient of this solution is that you won't be able to also process real gzip files within the same app.

---

Second solution: **Using newAPIHadoopFile with a custom/modified TextInputFormat**

You can use [newAPIHadoopFile](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext@newAPIHadoopFile[K,V,F%3C:org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat[K,V]](path:String,fClass:Class[F],kClass:Class[K],vClass:Class[V],conf:org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K,V)]) (instead of `textFile`) with a custom/modified [TextInputFormat](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.0.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/TextInputFormat.html) which forces the use of the `DefaultCodec` (plain text).

We'll write our own *line reader* based on the default one (`TextInputFormat`). The idea is to remove the part of `TextInputFormat` which finds out it's named `.gz` and thus uncompress the file before reading it.

Instead of calling `sparkContext.textFile`,

```scala
// plain text file with a .gz extension:
sparkContext.textFile("s3://mybucket/file.gz")
```

we can use the underlying `sparkContext.newAPIHadoopFile` which allows us to specify how to read the input:

```scala
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FakeGzInputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.io.{LongWritable, Text}

sparkContext
  .newAPIHadoopFile(
    "s3://mybucket/file.gz",
    classOf[FakeGzInputFormat], // This is our custom reader
    classOf[LongWritable],
    classOf[Text],
    new Configuration(sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
  )
  .map { case (_, text) => text.toString }
```

The usual way of calling `newAPIHadoopFile` would be with `TextInputFormat`. This is the part which wraps how the file is read and where the compression codec is chosen based on the file extension.

Let's call it `FakeGzInputFormat` and implement it as follow as an extension of [`TextInputFormat`](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/178751ed8c9d47038acf8616c226f1f52e884feb/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/TextInputFormat.java) (this is a Java file and let's put it in package src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input):

```java
package org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext;

import com.google.common.base.Charsets;

public class FakeGzInputFormat extends TextInputFormat {

    public RecordReader<LongWritable, Text> createRecordReader(
        InputSplit split,
        TaskAttemptContext context
    ) {

        String delimiter =
            context.getConfiguration().get("textinputformat.record.delimiter");

        byte[] recordDelimiterBytes = null;
        if (null != delimiter)
            recordDelimiterBytes = delimiter.getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8);

        // Here we use our custom `FakeGzLineRecordReader` instead of
        // `LineRecordReader`:
        return new FakeGzLineRecordReader(recordDelimiterBytes);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isSplitable(JobContext context, Path file) {
        return true; // plain text is splittable (as opposed to gzip)
    }
}
```

In fact we have to go one level deeper and also replace the default [`LineRecordReader`](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/178751ed8c9d47038acf8616c226f1f52e884feb/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/LineRecordReader.java) (Java) with our own (let's call it `FakeGzLineRecordReader`).

As it's quite difficult to inherit from `LineRecordReader`, we can copy `LineRecordReader` (in src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input) and slightly modify (and simplify) the `initialize(InputSplit genericSplit, TaskAttemptContext context)` method by forcing the usage of the default codec (plain text):

(the only changes compared to the original [`LineRecordReader`](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/178751ed8c9d47038acf8616c226f1f52e884feb/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/LineRecordReader.java) have been given a comment explaining what's happening)

```java
package org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.classification.InterfaceAudience;
import org.apache.hadoop.classification.InterfaceStability;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Seekable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@InterfaceAudience.LimitedPrivate({"MapReduce", "Pig"})
@InterfaceStability.Evolving
public class FakeGzLineRecordReader extends RecordReader<LongWritable, Text> {
    private static final Logger LOG =
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(FakeGzLineRecordReader.class);
    public static final String MAX_LINE_LENGTH =
            "mapreduce.input.linerecordreader.line.maxlength";

    private long start;
    private long pos;
    private long end;
    private SplitLineReader in;
    private FSDataInputStream fileIn;
    private Seekable filePosition;
    private int maxLineLength;
    private LongWritable key;
    private Text value;
    private byte[] recordDelimiterBytes;

    public FakeGzLineRecordReader(byte[] recordDelimiter) {
        this.recordDelimiterBytes = recordDelimiter;
    }

    // This has been simplified a lot since we don't need to handle compression
    // codecs.
    public void initialize(
        InputSplit genericSplit,
        TaskAttemptContext context
    ) throws IOException {

        FileSplit split = (FileSplit) genericSplit;
        Configuration job = context.getConfiguration();
        this.maxLineLength = job.getInt(MAX_LINE_LENGTH, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        start = split.getStart();
        end = start + split.getLength();
        final Path file = split.getPath();

        final FileSystem fs = file.getFileSystem(job);
        fileIn = fs.open(file);

        fileIn.seek(start);
        in = new UncompressedSplitLineReader(
            fileIn, job, this.recordDelimiterBytes, split.getLength()
        );
        filePosition = fileIn;

        if (start != 0) {
            start += in.readLine(new Text(), 0, maxBytesToConsume(start));
        }
        this.pos = start;
    }

    // Simplified as input is not compressed:
    private int maxBytesToConsume(long pos) {
        return (int) Math.max(Math.min(Integer.MAX_VALUE, end - pos), maxLineLength);
    }

    // Simplified as input is not compressed:
    private long getFilePosition() {
        return pos;
    }

    private int skipUtfByteOrderMark() throws IOException {
        int newMaxLineLength = (int) Math.min(3L + (long) maxLineLength,
                Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        int newSize = in.readLine(value, newMaxLineLength, maxBytesToConsume(pos));
        pos += newSize;
        int textLength = value.getLength();
        byte[] textBytes = value.getBytes();
        if ((textLength >= 3) && (textBytes[0] == (byte)0xEF) &&
                (textBytes[1] == (byte)0xBB) && (textBytes[2] == (byte)0xBF)) {
            LOG.info("Found UTF-8 BOM and skipped it");
            textLength -= 3;
            newSize -= 3;
            if (textLength > 0) {
                textBytes = value.copyBytes();
                value.set(textBytes, 3, textLength);
            } else {
                value.clear();
            }
        }
        return newSize;
    }

    public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException {
        if (key == null) {
            key = new LongWritable();
        }
        key.set(pos);
        if (value == null) {
            value = new Text();
        }
        int newSize = 0;
        while (getFilePosition() <= end || in.needAdditionalRecordAfterSplit()) {
            if (pos == 0) {
                newSize = skipUtfByteOrderMark();
            } else {
                newSize = in.readLine(value, maxLineLength, maxBytesToConsume(pos));
                pos += newSize;
            }

            if ((newSize == 0) || (newSize < maxLineLength)) {
                break;
            }

            LOG.info("Skipped line of size " + newSize + " at pos " +
                    (pos - newSize));
        }
        if (newSize == 0) {
            key = null;
            value = null;
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public LongWritable getCurrentKey() {
        return key;
    }

    @Override
    public Text getCurrentValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public float getProgress() {
        if (start == end) {
            return 0.0f;
        } else {
            return Math.min(1.0f, (getFilePosition() - start) / (float)(end - start));
        }
    }

    public synchronized void close() throws IOException {
        try {
            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
        } finally {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Haha, this worked, but it makes me extremely uncomfortable. I'm far from confident that the classpath will always be in the right order. Thanks though, I will use it for now and hope a better solution comes along.

Comment: @AlexHall I've included a 2nd possibility, which seems cleaner.